# In Elisp, how can I insert an org-babel JSON block into a variable with noweb?

Tags: org-babel, noweb

In Elisp, I want to insert the contents of the "gazonk" JSON block into a variable.

```
#+name: gazonk
#+begin_src json
{
  xyzzy "
}
#+end_src
```

, but I just get "End of file during parsing"

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :noweb yes
(setq example-data "<<gazonk>>")
#+END_SRC
```

Obviously, it's not valid JSON, but I want to insert the verbatim contents;)

EDIT: Here is a better example:

Here's valid JSON

```
#+name: gazonk
#+begin_src json
{
  "GivenName" : "Mortimer",
  "SurName" : "Smith",
  "NameSuffixText" : "Sr",
  "PreferredName" : "Morty",
}
#+end_src
```

Here's valid JSON, but enclosed, so not really valid;)

```
#+name: gazonk_enclosed
#+begin_src json
"
{
  "GivenName" : "Mortimer",
  "SurName" : "Smith",
  "NameSuffixText" : "Sr",
  "PreferredName" : "Morty",
}
"
#+end_src
```

This doesn't work with valid json

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results verbatim drawer :noweb yes
  (setq data <<gazonk>>)
#+END_SRC
```

, but this works

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results verbatim drawer :noweb yes
  (setq data <<gazonk_enclosed>>)
#+END_SRC
```

It's a general problem. I can't insert a code block into a variable, no matter what the language is. Here's XML:

```
#+name: fd7df9594ccfe7889b7e5817067733efc038967053e0ceb66b33bdc0ad7390d8
#+begin_src xml
<xml>
  <table>
    <rec id="1">
      <numField>123</numField>
      <stringField>String Value</stringField>
    </rec>
    <rec id="2">
      <numField>346</numField>
      <stringField>Text Value</stringField>
    </rec>
    <rec id="3">
      <numField>-23</numField>
      <stringField>stringValue</stringField>
    </rec>
  </table>
</xml>
#+end_src

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :noweb yes
(setq example-data "<<fd7df9594ccfe7889b7e5817067733efc038967053e0ceb66b33bdc0ad7390d8>>")
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: How are you evaluating JSON blocks exactly?

Comment: You seem to have loaded some Org babel library for JSON: when I try to evaluate a JSON source code block, I get an error: `No babel-execute function for json!`. And what works for you does not work for me. So can you please answer the question in my previous comment?

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure I understand. Blocks with JSON and XML are not evaluated. At least, I'm not evaluating them for now. I want to include the verbatim contents of a JSON or XML block into a variable, cause I'm using this JSON for example as a body in a curl request.

Comment: You are right - I think there is a bug with `:noweb-prefix` . E.g. I tried doing the multiline example towards the bottom of the page in [Noweb Reference Syntax](https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html) and I get no joy: `C-c C-v C-v` does not show anything different with or without the :noweb-prefix` header (although you should try setting it to `no` and see if that works for you - it may be version dependent). However even with that fixed, I don't think there is a way to escape the inner double quotes, so that Lisp can parse the string properly.

Comment: Can I somehow create a new block of any kind, where I quote the json block, before I noweb it into something else?;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `(org-babel-expand-noweb-references info)` returns the noweb-expanded string for the source block `info`. The structure of the source block info is described in the help of `org-babel-get-src-block-info`.

The only thing we need from the `info` for expanding of the noweb-references is `(language body)`:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(let* ((json-string (org-babel-expand-noweb-references '(emacs-lisp "<<gazonk>>"))))
  json-string)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: {
:   "GivenName" : "Mortimer",
:   "SurName" : "Smith",
:   "NameSuffixText" : "Sr",
:   "PreferredName" : "Morty",
: }
```

Disclaimer: This is certainly not the intended use of `org-babel-expand-noweb-references`. So be aware of potential changes in the API.

Maybe, you can ask [the people from Orgmode](https://list.orgmode.org/) whether this behavior could be held stable or how to tackle your problem differently.

Comment: Ok, that's just pefect;). Thank you. Can I ask if you know how to do it with "src shell" bash as well, now that I got you here?